# Standard way of checking if a file is readable?

Tags: c#, file

I know you can check if it is read-only, and then do a try-catch statement to see if it is readable, but is there a built in way of checking if a file is already being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`FileSystemInfo.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx) property, and check against [`FileAttributes.ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx):

```
var file = new FileInfo(path);
if ((file.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) != 0)
{
    // Do whatever you want for a read-only file
}
```

Note that that's *not* the same as whether or not you can write to the file. If it's already in use, then you may well not be able to write to it. Even if it *did* indicate whether you could write to it at the time you call the property, that wouldn't tell you whether you could write to the file immediately afterwards.

Basically, you *have* to use a try/catch if you want to handle attempting to write to a file which may fail. I would catch `IOException` specifically (or an even more specific exception, potentially) rather than catching all exceptions though.

Comment: Jon, is there some magic in `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` that checks if the file is in use or is this just checking if the file is marked read only?

Comment: @Mitch: It's *just* checking whether it's a read-only file. That's not the same as whether you could currently write to it. Will edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FileShare.None`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) when opening the file.  If any other process has a handle to the file, the call will fail.

E.g.: Check that a file is writable and not in use:

```
bool isWritableAndFree = false;
try {
    using (new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
    {
        isWritableAndFree = true;
    }
} catch { }
return isWritableAndFree;
```

Beware, however, that this type of code is vulnerable to [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) bugs.  It is often better to catch the exception at time of use.

Comment: This is exactly the algorithm the OP wants to avoid (for good reasons).

Comment: @usr, which is why I explicitly called out the primary issue, however, the OP also requesting an algorithm "of checking if a file is already being used", which I believe this provides.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I didn't consider that a file might be in use *after* I check if it's in use